# Split String into 2 sub strings on first occurrence of comma?

Tags: regex, flutter, substring

I am trying to split String in to 2 sub_strings on the first appearance of comma character.

Also the first occurred comma must be removed.

Example :

Suppose this is the string

Manhattan Ave, Brooklyn,NY,USA

dividing this into this

Manhattan Ave

Brooklyn,NY,USA

also to note that first comma has been removed.

and finally saving these sub_string into variables.

```
String Place = "Manhattan Ave, Brooklyn,NY,USA";
 String result_1 = Place.substring(0, Place.indexOf('.'));
 String result_2 ="";
```

Comment: What is the issue? The current code that you posted would seem to nearly work except for a `.` instead of `,` and not yet doing the second substring.

Comment: how to get second substring after splitting

Comment: `Place.substring(Place.indexOf(',')+1, Place.length)` (or `Place.indexOf(',')+2` if there is going to be a space after the comma)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```
String place = "Manhattan Ave, Brooklyn,NY,USA";
int index = place.indexOf(',');
String result1 = place.substring(0,index).trim();
String result2 = place.substring(index+1).trim();
```